# AWS CLI can access s3 but not other resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, ssm

Im trying to invoke s3 and ssm commands using an EC2 instance. For `aws s3api list-buketes`,it returns list of names. But for `aws ssm get-parameter --name "Customer"` it times out.

I have attached a profile with admin access to the EC2 instance. But it is the same. The instance is attached to a security group which opens to the internet.

I can invoke the same ssm command with success from outside the VPC.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a NAT or Internet Gateway on the VPC that your EC2 is in?

Comment: It sounds like the instance is sending traffic through a VPC Endpoint for S3. Is the instance in a private subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) mentined, my instance is in the wrong subnet.

Thanks for pointing it out.